# CSS style first column different than other columns

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to make the first column look different than the other columns. The following style selector does not do what I want. Can someone show me how I can get my first column inside milestoneRow to be different from the other columns?

CSS

```
.milestoneRow {
    line-height: 55px;
}

.milestoneRow:first-child {
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.milestoneRow:not(:first-child) {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="row milestoneRow">
    <div class="col-md-1">
        1st Column <br />
        3 Lines <br />
        Closer Together
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        2nd Column
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        3rd Column
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        4th Column
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        5th Column
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        6th Column
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS selector for first element with class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class)

Comment: Not the accepted answer ^ but the most-upvoted one by BoltClock answers your question.

Comment: Not a duplicate as indicated...the OP is actually trying to select the first child. The class has no relevance here.

Comment: @TylerH: What Paulie_D said.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yep, and the second paragraph of BoltClock's answer explains `:first-child`, which is what OP needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code

```
.milestoneRow:first-child {
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
```

only applies if `.milestoneRow` **is** the first child.

You need to select the actual first child of `milestoneRow` using a descendant selector like so:

```
 .milestoneRow div:first-child {
        line-height: 16px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: -10px;
    }
```

Comment: So, if I understand it, I was missing the first child of milestoneRow (the div). Thanks.

Comment: Exactly...your original code was only applicable if the `.milestoneRow` div was a first child. So it wasn't selecting any child divs of the parent at all.